# Angular 4 and Nodejs http post request implementation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I created small test application using **Angular 4** and **Nodejs**. I want to insert a text field value to the database either Mongo or mysql.
Following files I created *server.js* for running *nodejs*, Created *server>router* folder with another file *api.js* and Angular 4 *user component* created. 
What i did code shown below

*user.component.html*

```
<form (submit)="addHobby(hobbies,hobby.value)">
  <input type="text" #hobby>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

*user.component.ts*

```
addHobby(arrHob,hobby) {
    if(arrHob.indexOf(hobby) == -1) {
      this.hobbies.unshift(hobby);
      this.dataService.postHobby(hobby).subscribe((posts) => {
        console.log(posts);
      })
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Services folder contain *data.service.ts*

```
postHobby(hobby) {
    return this.http.post('/api/insertHobby',hobby).map(res => res.json().data);
  }
```

server router folder contain *api.js*

```
router.post('/insertHobby', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Welcome to post method");
    console.log(req.body.data);
})
```

When form submitting i'm getting output as only *welcome to post method*

req.body.data i'm getting as `*'Undefined'*` How to resolve this issue. Any way thanks to everyone..

Comment: what is "hobby" ? is it object ? , if not pass it like { hobby } in the body

Comment: 'hobby' is the text field value. I passed object format but i didn't get result

Comment: sorry typo it should be  { hobby : hobby  }

Comment: Okay i'm getting the result. i re write api.js as console.log(req.body.hobby); Thanks

Comment: I will put this answer , please accept the answer

Comment: there is no angularjs 4 , dude do see any js code ?

Comment: @valakhosravi sorry i didn't get it?. can u explain your question

Comment: since angular2 got lunched js codes turn to ts code and its not correct to call it angulajs 4 cause angularjs has it own updates and it might be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are not passing the variable as object , you need to pass it in object format as below :

```
postHobby(hobby) {
return this.http.post('/api/insertHobby',{hobby: hobby}).map(res => res.json().data);
}
```

Comment: Here i have 1 text field only, if i have more than 10 fields i have to pass this format only?

Comment: yes , hence preferred way is to pass it as an JSON object .